# SharePoint list pictures not showing in Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, outlook, picture, notifications

Me and other people in our company has this issue with Outlook client and Outlook Web App.

If i set notification alert for a sharepoint list and add new item to the list with picture, the picture is not displaying in notification email in Outlook (Client and Web App)

Screenshot from Outlook web app. Problem is same with client.

[image]

Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find solution, anyway I think this function is not working properly.

Only way how this worked for me, to be able to actually display pictures in email is to insert from address or edit source of multi text and manually add html picture link.

Also, picture cannot be saved on ShP, so it must be e.g. imgur.com etc..
So even if I saved picture in ShP folder and linked html img to it or I used function to insert picture from SharePoint or Computer this was not working..

Answer (score 0):

When the emails are received, are they received as html or rich text format?

Outlook and Outlook Web App give us three message format choices: HTML, Plain text and Rich text format. Open the email in HTML format and check whether the image displays.

For Outlook Client:

1. On the File tab, choose Options > Mail.
2. Under Compose messages, in the Compose messages in this format list, click HTML.

How to [change the message format to HTML, Rich Text Format, or plain text](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-message-format-to-HTML-Rich-Text-Format-or-plain-text-338a389d-11da-47fe-b693-cf41f792fefa).

For Outlook We App:

1. Click on the gear icon in the top right corner, then click on Options.
2. In the Options pane, select Settings.
3. Change the message format within the "Mail" section to HTML.

How to [change mail settings for Outlook Web App](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mail-settings-30c69a79-efc6-42d2-b740-4bf1c1f8a01c).

Comment: Hello Joanna, 

I checked both Web App and Client and i am running HTML settings in both. Also i added domain to safe-sender list.

I am able to view pictures from people directly, but i am not able to view pictures from SharePoint List notification alerts.